# Rectangle.Intersects doesn't work

Tags: java, collision-detection

I have two Gameobjects, a player and a star. When those two collide, the star should be declared as a new star, and the score of the player updated with 100 points. The problem is that the method i use for collision doesn't work:

```
private void collision() {
    if(player.getBounds().intersects(star.getBounds())) {
        star = new Star();
        player.setScore(player.getScore() + 100);
    }

    repaint();
}
```

The getBounds method of the player and star looks like this:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

The collide method is being called every millisecond (i know it is too often, it is just for testing), by a Timer with setRepeats(true).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How doesn't it work? What's the expected outcome, what's the actual outcome of running your code?

Comment: The expected outcome is that the star and the player should collide, and the star relocated, but they don't collide, and nothing happens, the player just walks right over it.

Comment: 1. Please post the intersects method.
2. Inspect the results of player.getBounds() and star.getBounds() by assigning those results to variables ahead of your if statement and setting a break point after them

Comment: public boolean intersects(Rectangle r)
Determines whether or not this Rectangle and the specified Rectangle intersect. 
Parameters:
r - the specified Rectangle
Returns:
true if the specified Rectangle and this Rectangle intersect; false otherwise.

The intersects method is a part of the Rectangle class, included in java.awt

Comment: Console log your `x, y, width, height` variables for both objects within the getBounds method, and show them here for a case when you believe they should be intersecting.

Comment: I found out that the y variable in the super of the star constructor was something else than the y variable used for collision detection. Sorry...